# How to read values from a Firebase Database and store them into an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Database that stores two values distance and a timestamp. I'm able to read the distances, but un able to read to more than 1 timestamp at a time.

```
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        ref.child("distance").child(i).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
            test = snapshot.val();
            test1 = JSON.stringify(test).replaceAll(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/g, "");
            myCreateFunction(test1, i+"");
        });
        ref.child("time").child(i).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
            time1 = snapshot.val();
            console.log(time1);
            myCreateFunc(time1["0"], i+"");
        });
    }

    function myCreateFunction(test1, i) {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.id = i;
        cell1.innerHTML = test1;
    }

    function myCreateFunc(time1, i) {
        document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = time1;
    }
```

This is a picture of my database

[image: This is a picture of my database]

This is the picture of the error that we get on our webpage

[image: This is the picture of the error that we get on our webpage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are only sending your first element of the array to the HTML create table:

myCreateFunc(time1["0"], i+"");

instead of something like this:
myCreateFunc(time1, i+"");

Let me know if this solved your problem!